# Smarty check selected checkboxes using array_search

Tags: php, smarty

I am trying to check checkboxes based on values in a smarty array.

In my php

```
$smarty->assign('locations_array',array(4,6,9,7));
```

I want to search through the array and if there is a match check the checkbox. 
Here is what I have tried in my template but I can't get it to work.I'm not sure how I can pass array_search the needle and haystack that it requires?

```
{foreach $locations as $x}
   {if $x.id == $x.id|@array_search:$locations_array}
   <label><input checked type="checkbox" name="locations[]" value="{$x.id}"/>{$x.title}</label>
   {else}
     <label><input type="checkbox" name="locations[]" value="{$x.id}" />{$x.title</label>
   {/if}
{/foreach}
```

Is this possible without creating a custom function?

Comment: I think I got it to work with  {if $x.id|array_search:$locations_array}

Comment: The @ is only used if the thing is an array and then the array is pased after the function. The problem is that only the last box is being checked despite having location id's that match the id's in locations_array

Comment: andrew:

Instead of: {if $x.id|array_search:$locations_array}, 
always use: {if $x.id|array_search:$locations_array !== false}
otherwise if $x.id is found in key 0 of the array, this if-test will fail when you do not want it to.  See warning here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without actually answering your main question (I don't know whether you can pass two vars to the function from the template), this could all be avoided by making a new array instead of `$locations` in the php file. Just looking at your posted code, you would want each element to have three sub-elements: `title`, `id`, and `checked`. This way you can avoid having to compare across arrays in the template side, and you can also avoid having to write a custom function.

Comment: Whether of not an box is checked is dependent on the individuals preferences so they need to be checked or not for the specific user.

Comment: That's fine; you should know what user you're dealing with in the php file also, so you can still create a custom array for that user before calling `$smarty->display()`.

Comment: :) you can just leave it without any up or down vote, voting is encouraged but optional.

Comment: But if you down vote and then upvote it should go back to zero. It jumps straight from -1 to 1, how does that make sense. By the way im going to do what you suggested and do {if $x.checked =='true'} and then do the array_search in php. My brain starts to shut down towards the end of the day

Comment: I think you have to re-click on the "upvote" (or "downvote") to remove it. You don't click on the opposite one.

Comment: Hmm logic tells me that if is upvoted then to move it to neutral I click the down arrow to decrease it by one. Maybe I should start a question on that. haha

Answer (score 1):

For reference I think that this is the correct syntax when using array_search.

```
 {if $x.id|array_search:$locations_array}
```

where $x.id is the needle and $locations_array is the array haystack.
I decided to go for a different approach based on eknals feedback

Answer (score 0):

i didnt works with array_search but i have some simply solution for your issue.
you can check your checkbox value with the locations_array in the foreach loop.

```
 **$i = 0;**
        {foreach $locations as $x}
           **{if $x.id == $locations_array[$i]}**
           <label><input checked type="checkbox" name="locations[]" value="{$x.id}"/>{$x.title}</label>
           {else}
             <label><input type="checkbox" name="locations[]" value="{$x.id}" />{$x.title</label>
           {/if}
**$i++;**
        {/foreach}
```